# System.Windows.MessageBox vs System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, messagebox

I am having trouble finding out what the key differences are between the two message boxes. What is the difference between `System.Windows.MessageBox` and `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox`?

Comment: You mention twice, in comments, that one message box "breaks your bindings" can you clarify, or have you, as suggested, started another question on that topic?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`System.Windows.MessageBox` was added  with WPF, and exists within the WPF assemblies (PresentationFramework.dll).

`System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` was added with Windows Forms, and exists within the Windows Forms assemblies.

If your program is a Windows Forms program, I would use the latter (`System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox`), as it won't pull in a dependency on WPF.  On the other hand, if you are developing for WPF, I'd use `System.Windows.MessageBox`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using a WPF form and one of the reasons I was curious about this was when I used System.Windows.MessageBox it was causing some of my bindings to break. When I switched over to System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox my bindings were left intact. Are there certain implementation aspects of the MessageBox that may be breaking my bindings? Thanks

Comment: @MisterXero: No - it shouldn't have any impact at all.  You might want to ask another question explaining what you're doing (with code samples) for that...

Answer (score 11):

One additional point should be noted:

If you want to display a message box in an application that is neither a windows forms application or a forms application (such as a .NET console application), you should not drag in assembly references for either as seems to be the common mantra all over the internet.

Instead, you should use [pinvoke](/questions/tagged/pinvoke) and call into User32 as follows:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern MessageBoxResult MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, int options);

/// <summary>
/// Flags that define appearance and behaviour of a standard message box displayed by a call to the MessageBox function.
/// </summary>
[Flags]
public enum MessageBoxOptions : uint
{
    Ok = 0x000000,
    OkCancel = 0x000001,
    AbortRetryIgnore = 0x000002,
    YesNoCancel = 0x000003,
    YesNo = 0x000004,
    RetryCancel = 0x000005,
    CancelTryContinue = 0x000006,

    IconHand = 0x000010,
    IconQuestion = 0x000020,
    IconExclamation = 0x000030,
    IconAsterisk = 0x000040,
    UserIcon = 0x000080,
    IconWarning = IconExclamation,
    IconError = IconHand,
    IconInformation = IconAsterisk,
    IconStop = IconHand,
    DefButton1 = 0x000000,
    DefButton2 = 0x000100,
    DefButton3 = 0x000200,
    DefButton4 = 0x000300,

    ApplicationModal = 0x000000,
    SystemModal = 0x001000,
    TaskModal = 0x002000,

    Help = 0x004000, //Help Button
    NoFocus = 0x008000,

    SetForeground = 0x010000,
    DefaultDesktopOnly = 0x020000,
    Topmost = 0x040000,
    Right = 0x080000,
    RTLReading = 0x100000,
}

/// <summary>
/// Represents possible values returned by the MessageBox function.
/// </summary>
public enum MessageBoxResult : uint
{
    Ok = 1,
    Cancel,
    Abort,
    Retry,
    Ignore,
    Yes,
    No,
    Close,
    Help,
    TryAgain,
    Continue,
    Timeout = 32000
}

var result = User32.MessageBox(IntPtr.Zero, "Debugging Break", "Your Console Application", (int)User32.MessageBoxOptions.Ok);
```

Comment: JFYI: System.Windows.MessageBox from WPF Presentation Framework is just a managed wrapper around this call. WPF MessageBox is not actually a WPF window. So if you are having reservations about doing what @stacy suggests, don't have those reservations.

Answer (score 3):

Both eventually call the same low level windows API as far as I know...

Comment: Interesting...When I use system.windows.messagebox it breaks a binding on my WPF form but the system.windows.forms.messagebox does not. Any ideas why it might be doing that?

Comment: @MisterXero what exactly do you mean with "breaks a binding"? Adding an assembly reference und using the full name shouldn't break anything. Both have an internal `UnsafeNativeMethods` class in different namespaces doing about the same, although the WPF implementation is more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

The both basically do the same thing, except `system.windows.messagebox` is WPF and `system.windows.forms.messagebox` is Windows Forms. If you're using WPF use the former, for WinForms use the latter.