# wpf messagebox vs. winforms messagebox

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

Is there any advantage of using

```
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show();
```

over

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show();
```

except that you don't have to reference WinForms assembly (which I have to do either way) and that you can set parent window more easily (which is no big deal)?

Comment: No difference, they both pinvoke the native Windows MessageBox() function.

Comment: Depending how stylized your app is you may want to roll your own. It's not that much work and there are plenty of examples to search for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [system.windows.messagebox vs system.windows.forms.messagebox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660587/system-windows-messagebox-vs-system-windows-forms-messagebox)

Answer (score 0):

`System.Windows.MessageBox` is from WPF, and is part of the [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) assemblies (`PresentationFramework.dll`).

`System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` is from [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms), and is part of the the [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) assemblies.

If your program is [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) , use the `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox`, otherwise go for the `System.Windows.Messagebox` (WPF).

I'm pretty sure they eventually use the same API call.

Comment: The question is whether the WPF version is better at anything? Anything. It certainly is worse in a few areas (eg. number of available button combinations).

Comment: Easier to style, the rest is pretty much identical to the WinForms. As said, use WPF on WPF and WinForms on WinForms if you don't need the added button combinations.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the styling? It contradicts what Hans Passant said... (at least this is my impression)

Comment: @TomaszGrobelny You might be interested in comparing their implementation, using a decompiler such as ILSpy. The Windows Forms version does more, but I don't know what it's good for. Maybe that helps you.