# Avoiding ambiguity with MessageBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, messagebox

I've run into this problem a lot lately. I often write programs using WPF/C# and want to use an `OpenFileDialog` or some other class requiring `System.Windows.Forms`. I also frequently use MessageBoxes (They become ambigious between the two libraries when Forms is added).

I add the reference, but (even with the shortcut) I have to use something like `F.MessageBox.Show()`. Is there a way to just temporarily use the `System.Windows.Forms` reference when I need or something else that will allow me to keep `MessageBox.Show()` intact?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Windows.MessageBox vs System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660587/system-windows-messagebox-vs-system-windows-forms-messagebox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft moved a lot of Windows dialogs to the Microsoft.Win32 namespace so you don't need to add a reference to all of System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: Right. For completeness, [`Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx) is part of PresentationFramework.dll, so a WPF project *should* already have a reference to it, but if it's removed for whatever reason, that's the one to add.

Answer (score 2):

You can place the following using directive on top of your files that need WinForms MessageBox:

```
using MessageBox = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox;
```

That will resolve tha ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the equivalent that is offered by wpf. This is System.Windows.MessageBox. It almost looks like the one in windows forms, however the parameters and return values may differ. Below is a sample to illustrate it's use.

```
var res = MessageBox.Show("Shutdown now ?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
if (res== MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Your answer is certainly in the right spirit, but I think the OP is already using the WPF `MessageBox`, but the WinForms `OpenFileDialog`. Moozhe's answer gives the WPF alternative for that.