# Bash whiptail equivalent in powershell

Tags: bash, powershell, drop-down-menu

I have a simple  bash script where I select files to use with an AWK script.
In the selection process I use whiptail.
[https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail]
I need to port this script to windows.
--> Is there a *simple* whiptail equivalent in powershell? <--
PS: It is currently running in WSL.

Regards
Holger Erlands-Petersen

Please see the filebrowser part of my bash script and the whiptail menu below:
[image]

```
# ------------------------------------------START Filebrowser() START--------------------------------------------
function Filebrowser()
{
# *** Inspired by Claude Pageau ***
# https://github.com/pageauc/FileBrowser
#
# første parameter er menuens titel.

    shopt -s nocaseglob # Skelner ikke mellem store og små bogstaver i filnavne (Windoze).
    DIR_LIST=$(ls *.csv -lhp | grep -v /  | awk -F ' ' ' { print $9 " " $5 } ') # Viser kun csv filer [filnavn + størrelse].
    shopt -u nocaseglob # Slå det fra igen.

    # Vælg fil fra liste. Valgt filnavn retur i 'SELECTION':
    SELECTION=$(whiptail --title "$1" \
        --menu "Pil-op/Pil-ned/Tab      <Enter> --> valg\n" 0 0 0 \
        --cancel-button Afbryd \
        --ok-button Valg $DIR_LIST 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
    RET=$?  # Reurkode. 0 = OK, 1 = Afbryd, 255 = ESC.
    
    if [ $RET -eq 1 ]; then  # Har brugeren valgt at afbryde?
       return 1 # Afbrudt ved valg
    elif  [ $RET -eq 255 ] ; then
        return 255 # Afbrudt ved ESC.
    elif [ $RET -eq 0 ]; then # Brugeren valgte noget (en fil).
        if (whiptail --title "Bekræft valg" --yesno "Filnavn: $SELECTION" 7 40  \
                         --yes-button "Bekræft" \
                         --no-button "Prøv igen"); then
                FILENAME="$SELECTION"
        else
                Filebrowser "$1" # Brugeren valgte 'Prøv igen'.
        fi
    else
          # Ukendt fejl i valg.
          echo $RET
          sleep 10
          whiptail --title "FEJL: Fejl i valg" \
                   --msgbox "Fejl ved skift til $SELECTION" 0 0
           logthis "Filebrowser: Fejl ved skift til $SELECTION $?"
          Filebrowser "$1"
    fi
}
# ------------------------------------------END Filebrowser() END--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If it does not have to be directly in the PowerShell terminal windows as a text, but may be as a regular Windows dialog box, WPF or Forms Assemblies. Details e.g. here: [System.Windows.MessageBox vs System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660587/system-windows-messagebox-vs-system-windows-forms-messagebox)

Note that neither of these approaches is portable to e.g. Linux version of PowerShell.